# stubbing using get method of a model basing on attribute

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, sinon

```
fileModel=new Backbone.Model({
"filename":"HigResolution4.jpg",
"uuid":"798643982",
"uploaded_by":"xyz",
"pixel_width":800
});
filenameStub=sinon.stub(fileModel,'get("filename")',function(){
return 'filename';
});
fileuuidStub=sinon.stub(fileModel,'get("uuid")',function(){
 return 'uuid';
});
```

I am using sinon.js for unit testing for BackBone script.I would like stub an a method basing on the attribute of a model. Can anyone please help what is the mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `withArgs` function on your stub if you want to check attributes.

[From the docs](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs)

> stub.withArgs(arg1[, arg2, ...]);
>
> Stubs the method only for the provided arguments. This is useful to be
>   more expressive in your assertions, where you can access the spy with
>   the same call. It is also useful to create a stub that can act
>   differently in response to different arguments.

Using your example:

```
var getStub = sinon.stub(fileModel, 'get');
getStub.withArgs('filename').returns('filename');
getStub.withArgs('uuid').returns('uuid');
```